# Add event to calendar on SharePoint through REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to add a calendar event to a SharePoint Calendar through REST API but i can't seems to find the relevant resources to achieve this.

If i understand correctly, the calendar in SharePoint is a `List` of events object, as such I should be able to add the event via ListItem object?

Sorry if this sounds wrong as I'm not familiar with SharePoint structure.

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, you have to work with calendar  just as you would do if it's was a list.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you targeting?

Comment: @Taterhead SharePoint 2013

Comment: Any info how it can be done using REST API?

Comment: @whatswrong unfortunately I don't know... we switched the solution to use EWS instead and there's a Java API for us to integrate. Maybe you guys can use the same thing? https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

Answer (score 1):

This is the example for OAuth token Authentication but REST part is anyway like this.

```
  var dataObj = {
        "Subject": "Birthday Party"
        "Body": {
            "ContentType": "Text",
            "Content": "Birthday Party for Cathy",
        },
        "Start": {
            "dateTime": "2016-07-03T09:00:00Z",
            "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo"
        },
        "End": {
            "dateTime": "2016-07-04T11:00:00Z",
            "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo"
        },
        "Location": {
            "DisplayName": "Conference Room 1"
        },
        "ShowAs": "Busy",
        "Attendees": [
          {
              "EmailAddress": { "Name": "Alex Darrow", "Address": "darrow.alex@company.com" },
              "Type": "Required"
          }
        ]
    };

    var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/";
    var data = JSON.stringify(dataObj);

 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true");
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");

        },
        success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //Success
        },
        error: function (data) {
        //          
        }});
```